# What is Dharma-Body of the Buddha?

Tags: buddhadharma, literature

> And then I remembered a passage I had read in one of Suzuki's essays. "What is the Dharma-Body of the Buddha?" ('"the Dharma-Body of the Buddha" is another way of saying Mind, Suchness, the Void, the Godhead.) The question is asked in a Zen monastery by an earnest and bewildered novice. And with the prompt irrelevance of one of the Marx Brothers, the Master answers, "The hedge at the bottom of the garden." "And the man who realizes this truth," the novice dubiously inquires, '"what, may I ask, is he?" Groucho gives him a whack over the shoulders with his staff and answers, "A golden-haired lion."

This story is quoted from Huxley's The Doors of Perception. What is the meaning of the story?

Answer (score 2):

The meaning of the story is that spiritual and mundane, mind and matter, information and media - are two sides of the same coin. Our nature from primordial times is pure and not different from Buddha nature.

We think there's some truth or escape to be found outside of this world, but the truth is, this world is only an interpretation we make, the escape then is to be free from the interpretation. The one who gets this is the one who loses all but still has the guts to laugh. We call this, the Golden-haired Lion.

Answer (score 0):

Body = The organs' center.

Dhamma-body = The buddha's dhammas' center.

What is the buddha's dhammas' center?

The best wholsome mind developments are buddha's dhamma center, such as 4 satipaṭṭhāna, 4 sammappadhāna, 4 iddhipāda, 5 indriya, 5 bala, 7 bojjhaṅga, etc. **Buddha is the center, the body, the summary of the best wholsome mind developments.** So, dhamma is his body.